# How to fly to Jamaica not through US or Canada

Tags: jamaica

How to fly to Jamaica, not through US or Canada as I have been in the UK for the last 14 days...
British Airways is direct but £3000+.

Comment: See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62195/getting-my-girlfriend-from-moscow-to-jamaica-bypassing-the-usa-no-visa for some previous options, but things have gotten much harder since COVID decimated flights.

Comment: See also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/156988/is-there-a-route-that-would-allow-travel-to-the-us-from-the-uk-or-schengen-area for information on flying from the EU to North America.  In particular, the information there states that you can *transit* via a Canadian airport without an isolation period;  you just can't enter the country.

Comment: You can fly via Canada, just saying (but need an eTA or visa, depending on your nationality)

Answer (score 4):

Countries (other than US and Canada) that plan to be flying to Montego Bay directly are Germany, Belgium, Netherlands, UK, Panama, Mexico & Peru. Most of these services are scheduled resume in Sep or Oct so your specific dates matter a lot.

This being said, it's a very fluid situation and it's difficult to predict what exactly will happen.